# What is the syntax error near '(' in my program?

Tags: c

I've just started coding in C, but no no matter what I try, I keep on getting a syntax error. "Syntax error near unexpected token '('"

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Hello World");
return 0;
}
```

I've tried compiling it by using

```
gcc helloworld1.c -o helloworld1
cc helloworld1.c -o helloworld1
```

and it compiles without errors, but it always screws up and gives me the syntax error message when I try to run it. Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this `#include<stdio.h>` --> `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: How are you running it?  The code is fine, so you must be trying to execute it incorrectly.

Comment: It can't both compile without errors and complain about syntax error. Syntax errors are checked at a time of compilation.

Comment: Execute `./helloworld1` instead of `./helloworld1.c`

Comment: "no matter what I try, I keep on getting a syntax error" that's cute

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler does not care) 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Answer (score 5):

According to BLUEPIXY's comment, it's quite clear that you call `./helloworld1.c` instead of `./helloworld1`. Thereby, your shell is expecting a shell script, but the C source code isn't a valid script (like bash or something like that). Hence, the shell (and not the C compiler) gives you a syntax error which doesn't have anything to do with the lanaguage C at all. Tried it with a file `test.c` into which I copied exactly the following lines of code:

**test.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Hello World");
return 0;
}
```

Then I called `chmod +ux test.c` to make it an executable, and finally called it in the terminal (which expects a bash script):

```
./test.c
```

yields:

```
./test.c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.c: line 2: `int main()'
```

The error is at line 2, because the first line `#include...` starts with a `#` and is therefore interpreted as a comment.

Comment: Can you explain how the OP's specific error message is happening?  Apparently whatever interpreter is being called makes it to the second line before hitting a syntax error.

Comment: just curious, what are the permissions on your `minmax.c` file? .. I would expect to get a "Permission denied" error,,, unless perhaps the execute flag is set for the `.c` file for some reason

Comment: @yano: I was also curious about that, because I had to do it manually. But OP is probably using a non-unix/linux/mac-os system...

Comment: ahh yeah could be. I know I've experienced some permissions weirdness in the past with cygwin, mingw, and cross compilers

Answer (score 0):

Don't execute the .c file, just execute the object code eg. `a.out`

In the terminal type: `./a.out`

Tip for C++:
Since the gcc has not returned error in compilation, you don't have error in your header file.
But in the future if you encounter (say) `iostream.h` not found, try giving an absolute path like:
`/usr/include/c++/7/iostream` instead of `iostream.h` in the header file